# Calabash-cucumber ios: how to delete a char in textField

Tags: ios, automation, calabash, calabash-ios

I am trying to delete a character in textField, using --keyboard_enter_char "Delete"-- and here is my code in step definition.

```
touch(query("textField")[0])        # touch the textField and bring up the keyboard, working
keyboard_enter_text("a")            # enter "a" into the textField, working
keyboard_enter_char "delete"        # I expect to see the "a" gone
```

So when `keyboard_enter_char "delete"` is executed

I got an error

```
typing character 'delete' is not yet supported when running with Instruments (RuntimeError)
```

and script stops.

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong or how should I delete a char from `textField`? Thank you!

Comment: try using this line in #2. `keyboard_enter_text("a", ``{wait_after_char:0.5}``)`

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the Calabash iOS Forum post you made, the correct usage is:

```
keyboard_enter_char("Delete")
```

We have an open issue around touching the delete key.

[Use UIAutomation JavaScript to touch keyboard Delete key #942](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios/pull/942)

The `:wait_after_char` suggested by Aravin will, mostly likely, have no effect.

Please don't cross post.

Comment: Don't cross post?  That comment is directed at Ke MA.  Not you.  Regarding your suggestion, it is OK, but I don't think it will fix the problem for this user.   Thank you for answering though.  I really appreciate it.